# Transition doesn' t work when class been removed by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, transition

I am new with html, css and js and working on some baby projects to take more experience. This time I am learning how to use javascript on my site but I have a problem. I have an error-msg-block that I want to change its height with transition. Also in js I add the class that gives its properties and after 3s I remove it. When I add the class the transition works but when the class is been removed the transition stops working.

```
.transition-msg {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


.error-window {
    max-height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(241, 128, 128);
    border: #888 solid 0.04rem;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
```

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn">
<div id="form-msg" class="transition-msg"></div>
```

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(firstnameInput.value === '' || lastnameInput.value === '' || passwordInput.value === '' || emailInput.value === '' || !termsBox.checked) {
    //alert('Please enter all fields');
    msg.classList.add('error-window');
    msg.innerHTML = '<p>Please enter all fields</p>';

    // Remove error after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {msg.innerHTML = ''; msg.classList.remove('error-window')}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is that in your CSS you've placed the `background-color` property on modifier class (your `.error-window`) and as soon as that class is removed the background is instantly disappeared because of the transition is set only for `max-height`. To fix this, simply move the `background-color` to the parent class, the `.transition-msg` class.

The second problem with animating the `max-height` is that within your JS code you're removing the HTML before the transition is done so the height of that `div` instantly becomes zero (if there's no content there's no height).
**The solution** would be to wait until the transition of `max-height` property is done and then remove the HTML.

Here's working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tpsfaLz4/)

Basically, what it shows is that you can use another `setTimeout()` method inside of your current but one with a delay of 500 milliseconds to match the CSS transition and then remove the HTML.

```
    setTimeout(() => { 

        msg.classList.remove('error-window');
        setTimeout(() => { 
             msg.innerHTML = '';
        }, 500);

    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use the transition to the main class
Here:

```
.transition-msg {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.error-window {
    max-height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(241, 128, 128);
    border: #888 solid 0.04rem;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
```